# How to log with a tree like structure

Tags: c#, logging, tree, log4net

I want to log with `log4net` (and I am doing this right now) to a file, but with log4net, there are just simple log outputs with a message each line.

Now I want to log to the same log file, but in a tree like structure. For example I've got the following method calls and each method logs its method name (there should be an indentation):

```
firstMethod().secondMethod().thirdMethod();
```

Should print this log for example:

```
2016-07-26 15:44:56,042    > firstMethod
2016-07-26 15:44:56,043         > secondMethod
2016-07-26 15:44:56,044              > thirdMethod
2016-07-26 15:44:56,045              < thirdMethod
2016-07-26 15:44:56,046         < secondMethod
2016-07-26 15:44:56,047    < firstMethod
```

The `<` and `>` signs are printed within the method at the start and at the end of the method.

Comment: Please note that your log output and the method calls does not really match here. `firstMethod` will be called, and will return **before** `secondMethod` is called.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very efficient but you can look at using the call stack to get the hierarchy of methods and then pad/indent each log entry based on the depth of the call in the call stack.

```
 StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();          
 StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
```

Alternatives could include using [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics/net-logging) or (possibly) writing [a custom appender for log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406634/Creating-a-custom-log-net-appender). Another thought is to forget about indenting and use the full namespace and method name to track where your log entry is coming from. This way you will still get a tree like view.

```
var methodInfo = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
var fullName = methodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + methodInfo.Name;
```

All that said, it seems like a very a-typical requirement. Do you really need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding another method for logging with parameter for enter/exit, and do the padding there :

```
int curLevel = 0;
public void MyLogInfo( bool enter, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string callingMethod = "", )
{
    string prefix;
    if (enter)
    {
      prefix = "> ";
      curLevel++;
    }
    else
    {
      prefix = "< ";
      curLevel--;
    }
    logger.info(prefix.PadLeft(curLevel+prefix.Length) + callingMethod);
}
```

You just call MyLogInfo(true) or MyLogInfo(false) - .NET will set the callingMethod name if you do not specify it yourself.

You would have to ensure that you do always call the method on entry/exit of each method you log - maybe check you don't decrement curLevel below zero.

Comment: Yes, just like this, but other outputs in the same method, should also be printed with the same indentation...

Comment: You could adapt the method to take an enum rather than bool as first parameter to indicate if you are entering the method (increments curLevel, prefix "> "), in the method (curLevel unchanged, prefix " ") or exiting the method (curLevel decremented, prefix "< ") & use the same technique of adding the padding - you may want to insert a second "string message" parameter so you can optionally output extra information

Answer (score 0):

You can use NDC to achieve similar behavior.  But it is deprecated.  Now, you can use Contexts and Contexts Stacks.  Check out this documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html

You can define multiple stacks (instead of indentation). One stack for a set of behaviors you want to debug.  Let's say you want to log creating a Sales Order and its Items.  In this example, this stack is defined in ThreadContext.  However you can define it in a GlobalContext , LogicalThreadContext or LoggingEvent.

```
using(log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["SalesOrderLogic"].Push("SalesOrder"))
{
    log.Info("Created the sales order");

    using(log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["SalesOrderLogic"].Push("Items"))
    {
        log.Info("Created the sales order items");
    }
}
```

And then you should add it to your configuration:

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%logger - %property{SalesOrderStatus} - [%level]- %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

DISCLAIMER: I did not test this code.

Note 1: The old NDC will appear in one thread.  So if you pushed a message in one thread, it won't appear in another.  And it has only one stack unlike the new Context Stack method.

Note 2: Don't forget to checkout Contexts. It is very useful.

Note 3: Also you might find it useful if you research Ninject and log4net working together